# Java/Libgdx Pixel game with individual pixel changing

Tags: java, libgdx, pixel, per-pixel

I am currently trying to make a game with pixelated graphics. The game is supposed to run with as few textures as possible. Instead of this it is supposed to generate the levels randomly, and fill in the pixels accordingly.

I would like to change pixels individually, since this way, I only can change the pixels that have to be changed, which seems to me to be the most efficient way.

What would be the fastest way in which I could achieve individual pixel updating/changing?

I have tried Pixmaps but they seem  to be very slow and in order to draw them as far as I could find you have to create a new texture from the pixmap for every frame.

Drawing each 'pixel' as a square texture also seems to be a very inefficient way.

Does java/Libgdx have a 'fast' way of doing this?

I also saw a lot of people in other Posts recommending to use bufferedimage from the Java2D library. However, I am not sure if this can be combined with Libgdx functions and textures, which I will need for some entities. As far as I could see it requires you to use a Java2D graphics window.

Can you still use some textures in java2D?

Comment: this approach doesn't scale well, because there are high-DPI displays nowadays and they are getting increasingly more dense

Answer (score 1):

I just post this here as i don't have enough reputation to comment; maybe you could use GL_POINTS when doing a

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
```

if you use Libgdx (which is more or less based on OpenGL) ?
Note this is just an hypothesis here.

Hope it helped :)

EDIT : Sarge Borsch who commented under is right. You shouldn't use the fixed function pipeline technique I suggested above, but, when rendering with VBOs and VAOs, you should do something like this :

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, size);
```

with size being the number of vertices you draw (36 in the case of a cube without using indices).

Comment: I'll have a look into it

Comment: This seems to be vector based though. It may work, but I'm not sure how well optimised it is.

Comment: Well, it should be the fastest way to render anything to your screen (except if you use VBOs) with LWJGL, though I have never made a speed test with both techniques :)

Comment: I try to get as close as possible to binary as possible :P I know the Java 2D lib has some good classes, but they are said to be slow. Doing a speed comparison is often hard.

Comment: The java2D classes are in any way able to draw things the way I want, but I'm not sure wether or not this means I can't render textures with the Libgdx library

Comment: Java is generally slow, but I'm most familiar with that language

Comment: Yes, but Java2D is not rendering through your system's OpenGL pipeline, which means it is indeed very slow. LibGDX offers you plenty of ways to render textures, if you want there's a nice tutorial [here] (http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx) but I understand you don't want to learn a new library from scratch ^^. Finally, just know there's an JVM option to force Java2D rendering to OpenGL pipeline : `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`

Comment: I have no problems with learning a new library btw, currently, I'm even considering switching to c++ xD

Comment: So I'll definitely have a look into it

Comment: please do not suggest using fixed function pipeline to people. it's deprecated (even removed from OpenGL ES 2+) and inefficient.

Comment: Java isn't slow.

Comment: @Spectre I haven't said Java was slow; I said Java **2D** was slow, because it does not take advantage of the GPU unless you use the technique I commented above.